# Excel splits a column into multiple column having no separator

Tags: java, database, excel, upload, delimiter

My file is being opened from a Java code where data is fetched from Database such that, for example the data in the column is:

> UCV000500095378E132030/7-108/03/20163905060022900908/03/2016208/03/2016BOUWRONG
>   A/C NAME5399

Instead of uploading the same in a single column, excel displays each data in multiple column.

*Note : Above Data is in concatenated form without any space in it in the Database.*

I am not able to identify the issue as why and how is the excel is separating the data so precisely even there is no separator in it.

Comment: What is the extension of the file?

Comment: the file which i upload is .csv and the file which gets downloaded is in .xls format and issue is coming in .xls format @BrenoQ

Comment: And the .csv file was generated based on this .xls file?

Comment: I upload a file in .csv fomat which saves the data in database and when i click on report button the data populates in .xls format with above issue @BrenoQ

Comment: I added an answer with my opinion of what probably is happening

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a CSV file which is something like:

> UCV000500095378E132030/7-1;08/03/2016;39050600229009;08/03/20162;08/03/2016;BOU;WRONG
>   A/C NAME;5399

Then you load that in your Java class and put the information into the DB with all the information concatenated in a single column.

Now you download the report as a XLS file, and you are wondering how Excel knows how to delimit each columns?

If that is the case, you are seeing things from a different perspective. The way I see it is that the XLS file is being generated from you CSV file that have all the delimitation and not from you DB. That way Excel can easily separate each column by the CSV delimiter.